# Facebook Life time for access_token

Tags: facebook, access-token

I see offline_access is been depreciated. I just want to know,how many days will my access_token will be there.

I mean,how many days will it take to reset?

How do i get user access token programatically .

Thanks in-advace!

Comment: There is some value to this question as it is particularly relevant now given the upcoming changes in fb's offline access privileges. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/.  However it does need rewriting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your Facebook access_token will expire in 60 days. Check this link: [Deprecation of Offline Access Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) to get a better idea.

See this link to know how to get [Access Token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). You could use Graph Api for that.
Hope it helps

Comment: :How do i get user access token?

Comment: :I guess,access token will be generated when users install the app,but i need access token,each time,when user comes to my application.

Answer (score 0):

you can ask for the token whenever and how often as you want. everytime the user interacts with your app (clicks a link through the permission dialogue, uses your page with JS SDK included, is on apps canvas ...) the token's expire date is refreshed by facebook and valid for the next 60 days. (but updated only once a day)

Comment: :Once the app is installed,facebook will not get permission again.How to generally take user access token.can you show me sample code.

Comment: 1) the user uses your app within the canvas or in your page (JS SDK included). facebook will notice that interaction an refreshes the token's expire date. if you ak for a token refresh (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/#extend_token) you will get one with the new date.

Comment: 2) if you can't use JS or the canvas build a link like asking for the permissions. doesn't matter if the dialog is shown or immediately redirected. in both casese you get facebook's respond that includes the code parameter. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#server-side-flow). note: you have to build your own api-call because the php-sdk ignores the expire-date param.